# Transfer learning with Faster-RCNN using tensorflow-hub.KerasLayer and tensorflow 2.x

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

#### System information

- **What is the top-level directory of the model you are using**: http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28.tar.gz
- **Have I written custom code (as opposed to using a stock example script provided in TensorFlow)**: yes
- **OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04)**: Windows 10
- **TensorFlow installed from (source or binary)**: binary
- **TensorFlow version (use command below)**: 2.1.0
- **Bazel version (if compiling from source)**:
- **CUDA/cuDNN version**: 10.0 / 7.6.5
- **GPU model and memory**: GTX 1060
- **Exact command to reproduce**:

I am trying to do transfer learning using faster_rcnn. 
Currently this model is not available through tensorflow-hub and thus I have to load a legacy module 
from the address given above. 
I am able to load the model, retrieving a tensorflow-hub.KerasLayer object and to pass a data trough it.

But now I would like to tune this network to my own dataset that only contains 2 classes, so I wonder how can I modify the KerasLayer object so the classification layer does not output 90 classes, but just 2 ?

If I am not using the right approach, what do you advise to solve my problem ?

I would like to avoid using tensorflow object detection API.
Also as it is mentionned in the documentation, legacy models are not trainable, but I do not think it would be a problem if I add my own layer, am I right ?

Here is the code I am using

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import numpy as np
import cv2 

# Run this once, then provide the local path where the model was downloaded, 
# instead of the below http address
model = hub.KerasLayer(
    "http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28.tar.gz",
    signature="serving_default",
    signature_outputs_as_dict=True,
)

image = np.expand_dims(cv2.imread("/your/image.jpg"), 0).astype(np.uint8)
# I would like this to output only 2 different classes in 'outputs["detection_classes"]'
outputs = model(image)
```

Comment: You said you could "load the model, retrieving a tensorflow-hub.KerasLayer object and to pass a data trough it." But when I am trying to execute your code in Google Colab, I'm encountering an error, `OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: /tmp/tfhub_modules/71d629f96ed560fa39e10d975f9aa546476adda8/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}`. I have tried loading the "tar" file to Google Colab but got the same error. We can try to help you if you can help us reproduce your issue. Thanks!

Comment: Yes it appears TensorflowHub cannot find the model it just downloaded. Once you have run the script I gave once, the model should be in your C:\Users\you\AppData\Local\Temp\tfhub_modules\unique_id\faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28\saved_model. By providing this local path instead of the http address, the model should be loaded correctly